# \b Regex include period as word

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to get a regular expression to return instances of a specific word, and that word only. The word as a substring of another word should not be included for example.

Here is my regex expression in Python 3.x so far.

`re.search(r'\bJohnn(y\'s|y)[.]?\b', string)`

However, since `.` is not considered a word character by `\w` then instances string included `.Johnny` are matched when I do not want them to be.

To clarify, period after the string is OK.

Is there anyway for me to include `.` as a part of the `\w` list?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: You can always just tell the parser to avoid instances where the full stop occurs before Johnn: `[^.A-Za-z]Johnny(\'s)?[^A-Za-z]`

Comment: Your example doesn't show you using `\w` but you can always use a character class to group together anything you want. `[\w.]` would be `\w` or `.`. `[^\w.]` would negate the previous.

Comment: you have to escape `.` with `\.` to use it as a literal

Comment: @JarrodRoberson: the dot doesn't need to be escaped in a character class since it has no special meaning.

Comment: Are you trying to match the trailing dot? Because it most likely won't match with `\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use negative look behind assertion to avoid that

```
re.search(r'\b(?<!\.)Johnn(y\'s|y)[.]?\b', string)
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/cN4aT3/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: May be OP wants to avoid dot on both sides: `(?<!\.)\bJohnny(?:'s)?\b(?!\.)` but +1

Comment: Thank you. Period after is fine, I was only looking to remove the period before.

Answer (score 1):

It's the other way around. Check if it's not preceded by a "`.`" nor followed by a `\w` with the [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<![.])` and `(?!\w)`

#### Regex:

```
re.search(r'(?<![.\w])Johnny(?:\'s)?[.]?(?![.\w])', string)
```

Comment: Maybe the beginning boundary can also be expressed with a `(?<![\w.])` look-behind.

Comment: @stribizhev indeed, I misinterpreted the question. Edited